# MATLAB - integral function vectorization warning

Tags: matlab, syntax-error, vectorization, warnings, integral

When trying to use the **`integral2`** function, I get the following warning:

"Integrand function outputs did not match to the required tolerance when the same input values were supplied in two separate calls with different size input matrices. Check that the function is vectorized properly."

My code is:

```
z1=0; z2=5;
t1=0; t2=10;

a=1:500;
b=linspace(0.15,0.02,length(a));
c=[a;b];
d=4.9e-07;

func = @(z,t) my_func((z + t),c) .* exp(-d.*t);

int_x = integral2(func,z1,z2,t1,t2,'RelTol',1e-3,'AbsTol',1e-3) ./ (z2 - z1);
```

`my_func` is:

```
function out = my_func(z_in,c)

z=reshape(z_in,1,numel(z_in));

for i=1:length(z)
  if (z(i)<0.0)
    z(i)=0.0;
  end
end

expfactor=exp(-z/150);

sB=5.5*0.9*4*expfactor;

mB=0.9*interpolate(c(1,:),c(2,:),z);

out=sB+mB;

out=reshape(out,size(z_in,1),size(z_in,2));

end
```

*z1=0*, *z2=9.6*, *t1=0*, *t2=3000* (i.e. all have the size (1,1)), and I have used element-wise operations, so not sure what the problem is.

When debugging, `my_func` is called three times, with *z* and *t* having different sizes each time (although same as each other; (14,14), (2,3) and (14,14)). When sizes are (14,14), the values of *z* are unique for each column, but the same for each row (e.g. [3,2,1;3,2,1]), and vice versa for *t* (e.g. [4,4,4;5,5,5]). But when sizes are (2,3), all values in the *z* and *t* matrices are unique. The warning comes after the second and third call.

What could be the reasons for the warning?

Edit: to accommodate the dimension requirements in `my_func`, I've reshaped *z* to a vector at the start, then reshaped the output back to matrix at the end, copying a similar function I've seen. But this returns the warning:
"Non-finite result. The integration was unsuccessful. Singularity likely."

Thanks

Comment: The problem most likely is in `my_func`, what you posted so far seems OK to me. Please read [mre], if we can’t reproduce the error, we can’t know for sure if our answer solves the problem.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo. I've updated the description with more context, which makes me think the problem is outside `my_func`. Does this doesn't make the problem/solution clearer? If not, I'll try to convert the code into a reproducible example.

Comment: The error message says that, given the same values in differently sized arrays, your function returns different results. This is what needs fixing. If I can’t run your code, I can’t fix it. The details you added don’t give me any useful information.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Hopefully you can reproduce from the example I've now added.

Comment: Your function assumes `z` is 1D, but you say you get an input of size 14x14. You can replace that loop in your function to be `z = max(z, 0)`, then there won’t be a dimensionality assumption in there any more.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. I replaced that for loop in `my_func` as suggested, but the original warning remains. I've since added new lines to reshape the input and output, which works in a similar function I've seen, but produces a new warning in this case. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The new error message just says that your function cannot be integrated. If you think your function should be integrable, then double-check that your code produces the values it should produce. I don't see any obvious red flags.

Comment: Note that `z=reshape(z_in,1,numel(z_in))` is the same as `z=z_in(:).'`, or `z=reshape(z_in,1,[])`. And `out=reshape(out,size(z_in,1),size(z_in,2))` is the same as `out=reshape(out,size(z_in))`.